# Don't display anything below some element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hide, footer

is it possible to hide every content after a certrain element (e.g. after a certain class of div)?

The problem is: I'm using a 1&1 webpage builder with a layout-template (annoying like hell) because of my boss. I'd like to remove the footer, but nothing has worked yet as it seems that the template prevents me from hiding the footer with simple CSS (I'm happy for any suggestions here as well).

But maybe it's possible to hide anything that comes after a certain element like a div or image (or whatever) so that I can put the element right before the footer?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Just inspect why you cannot hide it using relevant CSS rule

Comment: Since I have to use a template/layout provided by 1&1 there are certain rules preformulated. I don't have access to them so that I can't manipulate them. Neither can I tell you what rules they have specified. They prevent me from simply set display or visibility to none. Thus, the question whether it is generally possible to hide every content after a certain element (like a certain class of divs) to hide the footer.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use JS if it is possible on 1&1.

As you probably have JQuery you can do it like this:

```
$('.footer-class').remove();
```

or

```
$('.footer-class').css('display', 'none');
```

I don't think that 1&1 would have different classes or ids for footers each time someone refreshes it, so I think it should work.

Please provide a working example or your website address. This will help us.

Comment: Since I have to use a template/layout provided by 1&1 there are certain rules preformulated to which I don't have access.

Comment: You should give a link to website, which will allow us to inspect it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give us the footer's classes, id and all attributes? The simplest solutions is style="display:none" added to the footer